# question about operator in java with System.out.print

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me the difference and why ????????
I have an example:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 7;
System.out.println(a+b);
System.out.println(a+b+"String");
System.out.println("String"+a+b+"String");
System.out.println(a+b+"String"+a+b+"String");
System.out.println("String"+a+b+"String"+a+b);

output

9
9String
String27String
9String27String
String27String27
```

Comment: I want to know when it runs on what reason it is to distinguish whether this is a concatenation or a calculation

Comment: The differences between all the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had better check the **[String Concatenation Operator +](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)** from java specification, you will see the instructions like below,which will give you the answer

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To understand what's going on, consider that these expressions in Java are left-associative. The result of adding `int` + `int` is the arithmetic sum of the two values. The result of adding an `int` with a `String` is equivalent to converting the `int` to its `String` representation and then performing the `+` operation between the two `String`s, which concatenates the two values. Thus,

```
a+b+"String"` => (a + b) + "String"
              => (2 + 7) + "String"
              => 9 + "String"
              => "9String"
```

```
a+b+"String"+a+b+"String"` => ((((a + b) + "String") + a) + b) + "String"
                           => ((((2 + 7) + "String") + 2) + 7) + "String"
                           => (((9 + "String") + 2) + 7) + "String"
                           => (("9String" + 2) + 7) + "String"
                           => ("9String2" + 7) + "String"
                           => "9String27" + "String"
                           => "9String27String"
```

Answer (score 1):

Procedure to determine whether `+` means addition or concatenation:

1. Apply standard operator precedence rules to the expression to work out the order in which the operators are applied.
2. Examine each `+`.  If both left and right operand expressions of `+` are primitive or wrapped numeric, then the `+` is an addition.  Otherwise it is string concatenation.

Example:

Applying precedence rules to

```
a+b+"String"+a+b+"String"
```

means that it is equivalent to

```
((((a+b)+"String")+a)+b)+"String"
```

Then:

- `a+b` is addition
- `(a+b)+"String")` is concatenation
- `((a+b)+"String")+a` is concatenation
- `(((a+b)+"String")+a)+b` is concatenation
- `((((a+b)+"String")+a)+b)+"String"` is concatenation

This matches up with the output `9String27String` that you got for that case.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
System.out.println("String"+a+b+"String");
```

is assuming that you want to do `String` concatenation.

You could do

```
System.out.println("String"+(a+b)+"String");
```

or

```
System.out.printf("String%dString%n", a+b);
```

Comment: I want to know when it runs on what reason it is to distinguish whether this is a concatenation or a calculation

Comment: well if a string comes first it will do a concatenation

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the plus sign can be used to perform arithmetic addition.

It can also be used to concatenate strings. When the plus sign is used in this manner, the operand on the right is automatically converted to a character string before being concatenated with the operand on the left.

Answer (score -2):

Please understand the meaning of "+" in string first

Comment: Yes, I understand +, but I don't understand why a + b + "String" does a calculation, "String" + a + b + "String" does a concatenation that's my question.

Comment: If you execute a + B first, then it is an int type. If you then + string, do you think it is an error or output string type?So the problem is string = int + string

For string + a + b,I think so. The + of string is equal to string.append If it starts with a string, it will continue to append

Comment: String addition is a special case. You can think of it as if the compiler has an operator overload. ToString is called on all non strings. Int is boxed and evaluated

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64056946/edit) your answer to put that information in - don't leave it in the comments.